# Regex: how do i match repeating char or number

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching, repeat

I came up with this regex:

```
^[pP]{2}[^a-m](\d)+
```

To match: `ppt92617` `ppy92619` `PPr99999k`

Problem is, each number from 3rd index should not repeat throughout remaining part of the string. Hence, the 1st string would be a match, other two wouldn't. 
How do I do that?

Comment: " each number or char 3rd character should not repeat" - not clear!

Comment: Problem statement is corrected now.

Comment: Are `pp11`or `pp.1` allowed?

Comment: Yes. The application takes generic inputs and parses it for special characters for specific tasks. Like this one for password. The policy is bit more lengthy but I was specifically stuck with the repeated number input

Comment: Have a try with [`^[Pp]{2}[^a-m](?:(\d)(?!.*\1))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/mD8cP3/3)

Comment: Wow! That's even way beyond what I understand of regex. Will give it a try for sure. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Regex, that matches the sequence of unique numbers. Assume you find 5 unique digits, your code should like this:

```
^[pP]{2}[^a-m](?!.*(.).*\1)\d{5}$
```

1. `^[pP]{2}[^a-m]` is your code, you know it :)
2. `?!` is negative lookahead
3. `.*(.).*` matches one number inside surrounded by zero or more characters. `(.)` is the capturing group (looking like a boob).
4. `\d{5}` allowes the previous group to be 5 digits only
5. Together it checks five times if there is not the number used before (checks itself), because of **negative** lookahead.

It's pretty hard for me to explain it cottectly with my poor English. I have found and saved this regex years ago though it may be useful in the future.

Better look here, for the exact and correct explanation: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oU8dF5/2)

Comment: Just updated your regex a bit in order to show other examples as well: https://regex101.com/r/oU8dF5/2 Perhaps you should explain what you're doing here (negative lookahead, that is). Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot @nichar. Simple and just correct. Middle part is kind of bit hard for my newbie regex brain. Can help with that a bit?

Comment: Thanks again. I'm trying to match up a password input given by users against a simple policy on my Java application. Going by every character would be cumbersome, so thought of using regex instead

Comment: You'd give us some code and inputs again. I cannot picture what do you want, so don't hesitate to ask a new and detailed question and we try our best to help you again. ^^

Comment: By the way I'd never get mad if you check it as a correct answer if you use it >,<

Comment: My query is answered. Thanks for your prompt help. Will definitely post new queries in more detail if it comes up.

Comment: Ah! My level isn't up. I tried it already. It says needs 15 reputation points to be able to do that. :(

Comment: Length requirement of question is not clear to me. But you can simply change `\d{5}` to `\d+` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/nN7iH4/1) if needed @devN.

Comment: I need 5 non repeating numbers, hence {5}

Comment: This `\d{5}` matches 5 digits. This `\d{3}` matches 3 ones. This `\d+` matches 1...∞ ones (in our case only 10, because there are not more than 10 unique digits in the world).